# Python. Как скачать картинку, имея фразу для поиска?

Tags: python

Нужно в гугл картинках или в яндекс картинках скачать первую картинку, желательно большого разрешения. Нужно использовать средства Python, requests и bs4. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что классы постоянно меняются. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете изменить критерии поиска и искать допустим по тегу () и дальше уже задавайте остальные критерии поиска( размер картинки и т.д)
Насколько я помню то в Selenium это делаеться так:

```
elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

Comment: я знаю то то есть в HTML классы, есть id, но что такое теги?

Comment: Тэги это сами елементы HTML Документа. Например <p>Параграф</p> отображает параграф в документе. а <img> - картинку. а классы и тэги можно уже задавать этим самим тегам, чтобы к ним было проще обращаться <p class = "class1" id = "class2"> Параграф </p>

Comment: по тегам можно в супе искать, у меня именно траблы с поисковиком. Как спарсить именно то изображение, которое нужно? Если парсить самую первую картинку, то это будет какой нибудь логотип поисковой системы.

Comment: Попробуйте парсить елементы в массив и получать из него не первый елемент а уже тот который вам нужен